# Why are files getting deleted from the bin folder when I run the tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, msbuild, integration-testing

I have a .NET framework 4.5 solution and I'm trying to setup integration testing for an existing project. This solution contains a unit test project (**project A**) that references to a project that provides the base for integration testing (**project B**). This project references an other project that has al db up scripts to create the current version of the database (**project C**).

[image: Project references]

The copy to output directory option of the sql scripts in the database project (**project C**) is set to 'copy always', so that these script will be copied to the bin directory of the executing project.

When I build the unit test project (**project A**) indeed all sql script of the database project (**project C**) are being copied to the bin folder of unit test project (**project A**) (and also to the bin of **project B**). So far so good..

But when I run or debug a test in the unit test project (**project A**) all files from the database project (**project C**) in the bin of the unit test project (**project A**) are deleted before the first break point get hit (Assembly initialize)

Is there any way that these files will stay in the bin folder of the unit test project? Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure why its not working, but you could look into the [DeploymentItemAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx). It's possible that MSTest is deploying your test binaries and deleting the .sql files because it doesn't recognize them as part of the deployment.

Comment: Run the build/test with detailed verbosity to see which msbuild target is deleting the file